# ilmerge problem with System.Web.Mvc

Tags: msbuild, ilmerge

I have a build script which builds and merges 5 projects into one dll. One of the projects has a reference to System.Web.Mvc DLL which is residing within my Dependencies folder. I copied this file from the ASP.NET MVC3 folder into my project folder.

Here is the error after I run ILMerge.

```
Merging Primary Assembly
An exception occurred during merging:
Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: System.Web.Mvc.
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetAssemblyRefIndex(AssemblyNode assembly)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetTypeRefIndex(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.WriteTypeDefOrRefEncoded(BinaryWriter target, TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.WriteTypeSignature(BinaryWriter target, TypeNode type, Boolean instantiateGenericTypes)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.WriteTypeSignature(BinaryWriter target, TypeNode type, Boolean instantiateGenericTypes)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetBlobIndex(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetTypeSpecIndex(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitReferencedType(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitMethod(Method method)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitClass(Class Class)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitModule(Module module)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.SetupMetadataWriter(String debugSymbolsLocation)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.WritePE(Module module, String debugSymbolsLocation, BinaryWriter writer)
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(String location, Boolean writeDebugSymbols, Module module, Boolean delaySign, String keyFileName, String keyName)
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(CompilerParameters compilerParameters, Module module)
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
Rereferencing Merged Assembly
```

Any ideas why I am getting this?

Comment: Never mind! I needed to set CopyLocal to True...

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use ILMarge /lib option in your script like:

> ILMerge.exe
>   /lib:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
>   /lib:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies"